# EF and .Net core entities navigation properties causes cycle

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core-webapi

**TpVoAdvertisement entity**

```
public partial class TpVoVehiclesAdvertisement
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Column("stockId")]
    public int? StockId { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50)]
    [Unicode(false)]
    public string? Vin { get; set; }


    [ForeignKey("StockId")]
    public virtual TpVoStock Stock { get; set; }
}
```

**TpVoStock entity**

```
public partial class TpVoStock
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int? StatusId { get; set; }

    public int DestCountryId { get; set; }



    public virtual TpVoVehiclesAdvertisement Advertisement { get; set; }
}
```

```
public partial class StockDbContext : DbContext
{
    public StockDbContext()
    {
    }

    public StockDbContext(DbContextOptions<StockDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    public virtual DbSet<TpVoStock> TpVoStocks { get; set; }

    public virtual DbSet<TpVoVehiclesAdvertisement> TpVoVehiclesAdvertisements { get; set; }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
//#warning To protect potentially sensitive information in your connection string, you should move it out of source code.
//You can avoid scaffolding the connection string by using the Name= syntax to read it from configuration - see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2131148.
//For more guidance on storing connection strings, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=723263.
        => optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("SomeConnectionString");

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.UseCollation("Czech_CI_AS");

        modelBuilder.Entity<TpVoStock>(entity =>
        {
            entity.ToTable("TP_VO_STOCK", tb =>
                {
                    tb.HasComment("VO Cars Stock");
                    tb.HasTrigger("TriggerLogChanges_TP_VO_STOCK");
                });

            entity.Property(e => e.StatusId).HasDefaultValueSql("((0))");
        });

        modelBuilder.Entity<TpVoVehiclesAdvertisement>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasKey(e => e.Id).HasName("PK__TP_VO_VE__3214EC0752946F6B");
        });

        //modelBuilder.Entity<TpVoStock>()
        //    .HasOne<TpVoVehiclesAdvertisement>(s => s.Advertisement); have tried to do this one


        OnModelCreatingPartial(modelBuilder);
    }

    partial void OnModelCreatingPartial(ModelBuilder modelBuilder);
```

Hello everyone, i'm studying making web api, and met some troubles :)
I have a simple database and have generated entities using scaffold-dbcontext command. It has generated 2 entities TpVoStock and TpVoAdvertisement,I wand to make a relationship:
TpVoStock can have one tpVoAdvertisement and may be not), so this relationship is optional. I made some navigation poperties and it works fine, but when i send a request to my controller with siple line of code "stocks = context.TpVoStocks.Include(s => s.Advertisement).Where(s=> s.Id == 10944).ToList()" it returns me a cycle :( So It returns TpVoStock entity, then it's advertisement depending entity and then back to TpVoStock and so on :)

I'm toooo newbee in NetCore and EF to understand what am i doing wrong. Thanks for the help in advance!

Request response

```
//Stock
[{"id":10944,"statusId":2,"destCountryId":1,
//Advertisement
"advertisement":{"id":1,"stockId":10944,"vin":"VF3LCBHZHFS232605", 
//Again same TpVoStock
"stock":
{"id":10944,"statusId":2,"destCountryId":1,
//And Again same TpVoAdvertisement
"advertisement":{"id":1,"stockId":10944,"vin":"VF3LCBHZHFS232605"}]
```

I have tried to make navigation properties in different ways, use FluentApi, Deleting the project and go outside to breath a fresh air, come back to the project, all of it didnt help me :)

Answer (score 0):

The best thing to do is separate the concerns where your entities represent your data state, while DTOs or View Models represent the state you want to expose via your API/controller.  Often when it comes to exposing data via an endpoint there is a specific way you would like the data to be presented. This includes how related data might be included or excluded, or even flattened. Defining that model separately to the entities and projecting it via a `Select` or Automapper's `ProjectTo` avoids problems with too much data getting serialized or cyclic dependencies.

The other suggestion is to remove bi-directional references unless they really provide value. You can always query data as needed through a one-way relationship.

For instance if it makes sense that you will typically be querying Advertisements and want to access values from the Stock then have the Stock navigation property on the Advertisement, but remove the advertisement(s) from the stock. As an example, to get an advertisement for a given stock (searching by Id, or any value(s) on the Stock) if the relationship is only mapped from the advertisement, then instead of this:

```
var advertisement = context.Stock
    .Where(x => x.StockId == stockId)
    .Select(x => x.Advertisement)
    .Single();
```

... you can use:

```
var advertisement = context.Advertisements
    .Where(x => x.Stock.StockId == stockId)
    .Single();
```

If it is more of a one-to-zero/one relationship then the two tables should be joining on the PK. Having a FK is supported but this forms a many-to-one in the DB that EF just enforces as a one-to-zero/one behind the scenes. Something like this would be more like:

```
=Stock=
- StockId (PK)
- /* Stock fields */


=StockAdvertisement=
- StockId (PK, FK->Stock)
- /* Advertisement fields */
```

This way a Stock may be set up to have 0 or 1 stock advertisement records.